Integral inequality and Riesz Kernel
I am currently working on some Fractal Geometry, specifically how the Riesz capacity and the Fourier transform can inform us about the Hausdorff dimension. My book states the following inequality as an exercise:
Let $\varepsilon \in (0,\frac{1}{4}), z\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}, s\in(0,n)$. Then there should exist some constant $c$ such that (where $B(1)$ is the closed ball of radius 1 around $0$):
$$\int_{B(1)}\frac{1}{|z-\varepsilon u|^s}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(u) \leq c \frac{1}{|z^s|}.$$
Now, the author doesn't state whether this constant $c$ can depend on $\varepsilon$. However, it is later used to conclude the following ($\mu$ is some Radon measure, I don't think it's relevant to this specific inequality):
$$K\int\int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x-y|<\sqrt{\epsilon}\}} \frac{1}{|x-y-\epsilon u|^s}\lambda^{n}( \mathrm{d}u)\mu( \mathrm{d}x)\mu ( \mathrm{d} y)\leq K'\int\int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x-y|<\sqrt{\epsilon}\}} \frac{1}{|x-y|^s}\mu( \mathrm{d}x)\mu ( \mathrm{d} y)$$
where $K'$ is independent of $\varepsilon$; thus if $c$ is dependent, it must be in some way that when we integrate over $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x-y|<\sqrt{\epsilon}\}$, it becomes independent.
However, I have no clue how to solve the inequality, especially such that $K'$ doesn't depend on $\varepsilon$. Of course, we can rewrite to
$$\int_{B(1)}\frac{1}{|z-\varepsilon u|^s}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(u) =\int_{B(z,\varepsilon)}\frac{1}{|u|^s}\mathrm{d}\lambda^n(u)$$
and for $k\in B(z,\epsilon)$ such that $|k|\geq|z|$, we can bound by $|z|^{-s}$, and integrate. But what about the other part of the ball? I'm quite stuck.
